# How to avoid Jenkins Job DSL to overwrite triggers in pipelines

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

Let's have a seed job in Jenkins Job DSL Groovy which generates a pipeline this way:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("DSL") {
            steps {
                jobDsl scriptText: """pipelineJob("test-pipeline-generated") {
                    definition {
                        cps {
                            script 'pipeline { agent(any); triggers{ cron("H/2 * * * *") }; stages { stage("Some") { steps { echo "Working ..." } } } }'
                        }
                    }
                }
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It generates a pipeline job which has to be triggered manually for the first time to process `triggers` definition and everything works fine. However, when the seed job is triggered again it **overwrites** the pipeline job definition and triggers are **gone** again. This means that seed job disables all such jobs.

Does anybody know if there is any solution for it?

We would like to keep triggers there and if there are changes in the pipeline it will be processed after the first run. We would like to not specify triggers in job DSL because users are used to specify them in the pipeline definition.

Answer (score 0):

There is a switch for not regenerating existing jobs/views:

[image: Jenkins: Action for existing jobs and views]

DSL API:

```
ignoreExisting()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you put the triggers inside the template pipeline (as well as in the seed job), it will remain for the next runs as well.

Comment: Then we would have duplicated triggers configuration which is not very nice. I would like to see a way to say "keep triggers untouched".

Comment: You won't have duplicate triggers if it is of the same type - the pipeline overwrite the one in the config.xml once loaded

Comment: ok, agree, but we will have two definitions of the same: one in Job DSL, one in pipeline definition

Comment: Duplicating effort and having to maintain the same triggers in both the dsl and the pipeline is not really a solution.